# Porting Java AES encryption code to node.js

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, encryption, meteor

I'm trying to port following AES encryption code to nodejs from java.

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class AESEncryption {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String key = "AsKUMDPsr7dfuk6fxgpfRdwm6de+MArf4SdAds9aq";
            byte[] hashedKey = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1").digest(key.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(hashedKey, 2, 16, "AES"); // don't know how to port this to nodejs

            String plainText = "test123";
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            cipher1.init(1, keySpec);
            System.out.println(Base64.encodeBase64String(cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"))));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Tried writing following nodejs code but encrypted texts are different.

```
crypto = require('crypto');

var key = 'AsKUMDPsr7dfuk6fxgpfRdwm6de+MArf4SdAds9aq';
var shasum = crypto.createHash('sha1');
shasum.update(key);
var encrypted_key = shasum.digest('').slice(2, 18).toString('utf8');
console.log(encrypted_key);

var plain_text = 'test123';
var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-128-ecb', encrypted_key, '');
var encrypted_text = cipher.update(plain_text, 'utf-8', 'base64');
encrypted_text += cipher.final('base64');
console.log(encrypted_text);
```

How can I port `SecretKeySpec` which created from byte array?

Comment: You know that CryptoJS and sjcl are both available as Meteor packages don't you?

Comment: @MichelFloyd Yes, but I couldn't find a way to call createCipheriv and preferred the Npm.require way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var encrypted_key = shasum.digest('').slice(2, 18).toString('utf8');
```

should be

```
var encrypted_key = shasum.digest().slice(2, 18);
```

to get a `Buffer` and slice the correct bytes from it.

---

#### Security considerations:

**Never use [ECB mode](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/14487/13022)**. It's deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. You should at the very least use a randomized mode like [CBC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/22260/13022) or [CTR](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2378/13022). It is better to authenticate your ciphertexts so that attacks like a [padding oracle attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18185/13022) are not possible. This can be done with authenticated modes like GCM or EAX, or with an [encrypt-then-MAC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/13022) scheme.